# In google protocol buffer writeTo method string values is not encoded

Tags: protocol-buffers

After writing a output stream to writeTo method my file showing string value as I set

Miteshr new group"
2014 01 11z

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 1):

Strings in protobuf are UTF-8 encoded, which means that the text portions will be plainly readable in any tool that generally works with text. If you look in a binary editor, however, you'll notice that your other data is encoded differently and not as text.

UTF-8 is pretty much ubiquitous these days.